# Correct OOP-design, if I want to call non-const function of const reference?

Tags: c++, oop, reference, constants

I guess I still have to learn a lot about not only C++, but object oriented programming itself. In a recent C++-project, I came across one question quite frecuently:  If I have a situation where I want to pass a const reference to some object, how can I use non-const functions of that object?

Let me give an example: Say I have a class with some data and a function with a small calculation with that data, for instance

```
class Person
{
    private:
    float weight;
    float height;
    float age;
    ...

    public:
    float bodyMassIndex();
};
```

Now I have another class with different expertise, e.g.

```
class GymInstructor
{   
    private:
    float knowledge;
    int age;
    ...

    public:
    int recommendDumbbellWeight(const Person &person);
};
```

Now say the function `GymInstructor::recommendDumbbellWeight` wants to use the function `Person::bodyMassIndex()` in its calculation.

Here is the list of things I should avoid or cannot do:

- Making a local copy of the `Person` inside `recommendDumbbellWeight` (so avoid something like `GymInstructor::recommendDumbbellWeight(Person person)`) because I do not need to and it slows down my program
- Giving a pointer to `recommendDumbbellWeight` by something like `GymInstructor::recommendDumbbellWeight(Person *pPerson)`, because I just nead read-only access and should therefore avoid any errors by giving write-access to `recommendDumbbellWeight`
- Make Person::bodyMassIndex a `const` function, because it depends on the state of the object, here e.g. `weight` and `height`.
- Moving the function `bodyMassIndex()` to some other class, because it uses the data of the `Person`, so there is no real reason why another object should perform that calculation. If so, I would have to pass all the data to that other class.
- Say, `GymInstructor::recommendDumbbellWeight` needs a lot more results of small calculations like `Person::bodyMassIndex()`, then I also should avoid just passing the result of the calculation with something like `GymInstructor::recommendDumbbellWeight(float bodyMassIndex, float experience, float fitness, ...` because it blows up my parameter list which looks ugly and produces unnecessary code.

So what is actually left? I would love to call `Person::bodyMassIndex()` in `GymInstructor::recommendDumbbellWeight(const Person &person)`, but I can't, because `person` is a const reference.
I assume that either I am too stupid to see the very obvious solution or there is something fundamentally wrong in my design. How would I solve my problem?

Comment: " + Make Person::bodyMassIndex a const function, because it depends on the state of the object, here e.g. weight and height."   **This is not a reasonable argument for non-constness.**  string::c_str() is const and is entirely dependent on state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring a method `const` is somewhat like making a promise that it won't try to modify the object. It will not deny you access to the object state and you still will be perfectly able to call it for non-const objects.
 So yes, the solution is `float bodyMassIndex() const;`

Comment: Ahh, by declaring the function as `const`, I always only thought of something like `const float bodyMassIndex();`. Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: Well if you want to speculate further, one could say that non-static methods have "invisible" `*this` parameter, and cv-qualifiers of the method apply to that parameter

Answer (score 0):

Declare method as const since it's a getter anyways
   `float bodyMassIndex() const;`

Answer (score 0):

The requirement that `Person::bodyMassIndex()` should not be const is unreasonable and quite ridiculous. 
The only argument that `Person::bodyMassIndex()` should not be const is that it actually **changes the state of the Person object**. It doesn't.

So having `Person::bodyMassIndex()` non-const in the first place is a bug. A mistake in the class design.